# How can a ngdoc root/overview page be defined?

Tags: angularjs, ngdoc

I have a working documentation page with a *API Documentation* section and a *Tutorial* section. When I click *Tutorial* in the breadcrumb navigation, a blank page appears in the content area and the browser title bar says "core-js: Error: Page Not Found!". The same behaviour can be observed for the *API Documentation* button.

What file will be loaded when a main navigation bar link (or main breadcrumb item) is clicked? How can this behaviour be configured in the Gruntfile.js?

I used the Firefox development tools to monitor the ajax request for the according file, but don't see a request when I click the *Tutorial* link.
I tried several options in the Gruntfile.js and tried to place a 
tutorial.html file into my generated documentation directory - without success.

Is it impossible to have content on the pages of the root sections?

I configured the grunt task to open the *Intro* page when the project link *core-js* of the main navigation bar was clicked, I would appreciate this behaviour for the *Tutorial* link, but I would prefer to have a specific *Tutorial* page.

My current Gruntfile code:

```
ngdocs: {
    options: {
        dest: 'doc/generated',
        html5Mode: false,
        startPage: '/tutorial/intro',
        title: 'core-js',
        titleLink: '/#/tutorial/intro',
        bestMatch: true
    },
    api: {
        title: 'API Documentation',
        src: config.doc.files.api
    },
    tutorial: {
        title: 'Tutorial',
        src: config.doc.files.tutorial
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `config.doc.files.api` is set to an array of filenames. Just to be sure, it should resolve to something like:

```
api: {
   title: 'API Documentation',
   src: ['./foo.js', 'bar.js']
}
```

File paths are relative to the grunt file. 
To create an overview page, simply create a file (e.g. 'tutorial.txt'):

```
/**
 * @ngdoc overview
 * @name index
 * @description your text here
 */
```

and add the file to the `src` array in the `api` section.